# Sorting an array of objects based on object property

Tags: ruby

I have an array like so:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "aabb",
    "commit": {
      "id": "1",
      "message": "aabb ",
      "committed_date": "2018-04-04T15:11:04.000+05:30",
      "committer_name": "ak",
      "committer_email": "ak@ak.in"
    },
    "protected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "aacc",
    "commit": {
      "id": "2",
      "message": "aacc ",
      "committed_date": "2018-02-04T15:11:04.000+05:30",
      "committer_name": "ak",
      "committer_email": "ak@ak.in"
    },
    "protected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "aadd",
    "commit": {
      "id": "3",
      "message": "aadd ",
      "committed_date": "2018-04-01T15:11:04.000+05:30",
      "committer_name": "ak",
      "committer_email": "ak@ak.in"
    },
    "protected": false
  }
]
```

I need to sort this array based on `committed_date`. How do I do that?

Do I have to loop and write a custom sorting function or does Ruby offers something out-of-box?

Comment: `arr.sort_by { |h| h[:commit][:committed_date] } #=> [{:name=>"aacc",...}, {:name=>"aadd",...}, {:name=>"aabb",...}]`. There is no need to convert the date to a date object. This is a pure-Ruby question so you don't need the Rails tag.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Please post your solution as answer

Comment: This is Cary's dad. Sorry, he's gone to bed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland should remember to log out. Dads are sneaky.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Apology, Cary is aged retired prof right? :| then what is age of Cary's dad?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That applies if they're all in the same +05:30 time zone, otherwise you need to do something to standardize the zones.

Comment: @muistooshort all dates are in uniform timezone. Thanks.

Comment: Nevertheless (timezones), @muistooshort has a good point. To protect against a possible future change that admits multiple time zones, one could write  `arr.sort_by { |h| DateTime.iso8601(h[:commit][:committed_date]) }`. See [DateTime::iso8601](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-iso8601).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sort_by

```
array.sort_by {|obj| obj.attribute}
```

Or more concise

```
array.sort_by(&:attribute)
```

In your case

```
array.sort_by {|obj| obj[:commit][:committed_date]}
```

Comment: I went ahead with this solution. Thanks Umar and Cary.